# how can i wait indefinitely for an answer from a webrequest in c#

Tags: c#, timeout, webrequest

I'm making a webrequest to a page that is responding very slowly. the size and duration of the response varies. sometimes it takes more than 5 minutes to finish reply. the browser waits successfully for the answer, but my webrequest breaks off with error 504 beforehand.
How can I prevent this.
here my code (I set all timeouts to -1, without any success)

```cs
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(req_url));
                request.Accept = "text/html";
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla / 4.0(compatible; MSIE 6.0; " + "Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
                request.Timeout = -1;
                request.KeepAlive = true;
                request.ReadWriteTimeout = -1;
                request.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;
                request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
                request.ReadWriteTimeout = -1;
                request.ContinueTimeout = -1;
```

and here is an example query:

http://www.bml3.nrw.de/service/bml?&REQUEST=GetFeature&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&srs=EPSG:25832&TYPENAMES=bml:Borehole&BBox=359538.615320737%2C5699402.64151475%2C364538.615320737%2C5704402.64151475,EPSG:25832

Comment: I am also getting an error 504 when opening your link with chrome. I think the problem isn't your web request, but the source page

Comment: I just opened it successful with chrome. the size of the response depends on the bbox, with a smaller bbox the answer is "faster". eg: 500x500 http://www.bml3.nrw.de/service/bml?&REQUEST=GetFeature&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&srs=EPSG:25832&TYPENAMES=bml:Borehole&BBox=361708.997437441%2C5701707.70304213%2C362208.997437441%2C5702207.70304213,EPSG:25832 or 1000x100 http://www.bml3.nrw.de/service/bml?&REQUEST=GetFeature&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&srs=EPSG:25832&TYPENAMES=bml:Borehole&BBox=361458.997437441%2C5701457.70304213%2C362458.997437441%2C5702457.70304213,EPSG:25832

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the request timeout (in seconds) in the web.config 
`<httpRuntime executionTimeout="1000" />`

web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="300" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

`httpWebRequest.GetResponse()` is disposable and should be wrapped with using() closures. This is 90% likely to be your underlying problem.

```
using (var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
{
}
```